# Missing Posts when Accessing /me/feed via Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am currently attempting to retrieve all the posts on my Timeline via Facebook's Graph API.  My Likes and Links and Posts appear to retrieve just fine, but posts from friends do not appear to be displaying.

For instance, a friend shared a link on my timeline, and that is currently not displaying in the returned data in my request to /me/feed.

I've tried turning on all permissions, but can't seem to get that particular post in my return data.  Is there something obvious I'm overlooking?

Thank you for any assistance,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

If a users permissions for a post are set to anything other than public if could be omitted from the result set.

Check the privacy for that missing post.

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/

me/feed privacy: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed%3Ffields%3Dprivacy

Comment: Since the post is on my timeline, I should be able to see the post.  When I view it on my timeline, the privacy says "Your friends."

Comment: your application is not your friend, try to set that post to public and see if it is visible.

Comment: just to give you an idea, if it is friends only, and you have one of your friends auth your app and run their home feed, they will see that post.
let me do a few permissions tests on my own feed, if you would like, i will auth in your app / friend you and we can do a few feed tests with friend of friend and friend only perms.

Comment: if you wish send me add request at fb.com/shawnsspace

Comment: Thank you for your consideration, Shawn.  After looking into this, it appears that my particular friend has some serious security applied to his settings.  I have been able to retrieve all my friends' posts as expected except for this particular friend.

Answer (score 0):

Please test with Graph API explorer, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Ffeed, click "**Get access token**" button and tick "**read_stream**" check box under "**Extended Permissions**" tab. Then submit and proceed authentication process.

After authentication dialog done, click "**Submit**" and try to test to get the link shared by your friend. I've no problem to see this kind of feed. Of course, you can create a new account and behave as your friend for easier to test, otherwise you need go through pagination to get the target feed.

Comment: That is the URI that I have been using.  My friend's post does not show up in the JSON result, but I can clearly see it on my Timeline...

Comment: 1. You should try to create a new account to test. And make sure the feed you posted is in front of the first page. Then go to  Graph API explorer again. 2. You may also try to get post_id(you should know how to get it, isn't?) of the post which have the problem, and visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20post_id%2C%20created_time%2C%20actor_id%2C%20target_id%2C%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3Dme()%20AND%20post_id%3D'YOUR_POST_ID'%20LIMIT%20150%0A (replace YOUR_POST_ID)

Comment: Hmmm... alright, now we're getting somewhere.  When I do a query on that post id (replacing with the actual id number), the result is an empty data set.  This could possibly just be a bug?

Comment: How about https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20post_id%2C%20created_time%2C%20actor_id%2C%20target_id%2C%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20post_id%3D'YOUR_POST_ID'%20LIMIT%20150%0A ?